# REQUIRESCRIPT and static resources in list onclick javascript button after “Serve Static Resources from force.com domain” critical update

Tags: visualforce, javascript, force.com, custom-button, static-resources

I just want to raise the problem again. The issue with loading static resources using REQUIRESCRIPT in list onclick javascript button can be reproduced again in Summer 15 preview. Anyone else can reproduce? Any ideas/comments?

Please, refer to the last comments of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68390/using-static-resources-in-onclick-javascript-buttons-after-serve-static-resourc).

Thanks